# What is the name of a comic character with a yellow suit that looks like a moth or mosquito?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero

Below is a picture. It doesn't look like Mosquito Man, Yellowjacket, or the Moth. My son received it in a pile of giveaway toys (including both DC and Marvel characters) so no packaging was available.

[image]

Comment: That's the Ben-10 logo on its chest.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that's from the show ["Ben 10"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10), not DC-comics. It would appear to be on of his forms, thought I'm not sure the name of that form, or which series that form is from (there are at least 4 different series with different forms).

Comment: I never understood why they called it Ben 10, since they obviously planned on adding more forms and they obviously planned on Ben getting older.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kevin Did they plan on making him older? Also, it's a pun on his name, Ben Tennyson.

Comment: Solution: do a reverse image search. Similar thing happened to me. I got an action figure from the thrift store but had no idea what franchise it was from. I did a reverse image search and found out it's a character from some game called Bioshock.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That character isn't from Marvel or DC. It's "[Ultimate Big Chill](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Chill)" from the *Ben Ten* franchise.

[image: Ultimate Big Chill]

Your version seems to be missing part of its head.

Answer (score 5):

It's from Ben 10:

Ben 10 Ultimate Alien Ultimate Big Chill Haywire

e.g.
http://www.godrules.net/store/Figures01.htm

A good sign is the symbol on his front, the green "hourglas"